# Why will some client side code not work?

Tags: jquery

I found the coolest slideshow type thing done with jQuery, when I copy all the files over to my computer to try to see how it works, I will not work.

It's just javascript, css, images, and html page

Why will it not work if it is not a serverside language?

[example page](http://btk.name/jquery/slide/)

Comment: Very hard to help with out a link to the page or some code.

Comment: @MitMAro the link is above labeled "example page"

Comment: Exactly what parts are not working?  I copied the files onto my own machine, and the javascript worked as expected.  The images didn't show up but that was just because they weren't in the correct directory for the css.

Comment: I can get the images to show because i copied every file over but the problem is it shows no js errors but when you click a button for the next slide to show it does nothing, also it does not play the auto slide show either

Comment: Nice a downvote but nobody else can get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the jquery file was corrupted and that's why it did not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to be a smart alek, but you did remember to also download the jquery script file right?

And make sure you maintained the original directory and file structure.

Comment: This would be my guess as well.